# A multimedia-rich application for windows, is Python enough good?

Tags: python, user-interface, programming-languages, multimedia

I'm going to develop a multimedia application which is running mostly on windows.
I don't know whether python is a good choice or not and which GUI library (Wxpython or pyqt) is suitable for that. Maybe pyQt is enough(like it).

The major features of the application include:

1. Must have a rich GUI, a great look and feel which is fast.
2. Have the ability to play/pause video and audio files with fast seeking ability( seek and play a specific portion of a long  media file quickly upon request, CRITICAL FEATURE)
3. Have the ability to control the speed of playback without losing so much quality
4. Can show subtitles for video files

Since I'm new to Python world, it's wise to dive straightly into Python 3.x, the problem is that python 3 is fairly new and most of the resources are still based on python 2.x. Will I need to work back on python 2.x? are the required libraries compatible with python 3.x?
Thanks

Comment: who says its wise to use Python 3? It isn't, most of the useful libraries still have not been fully ported to 3 it at all.

Comment: Yellow. Thats about the best answer your going to get because this question is entirely subjective to the person who answers it. Person from x language would argue one thing while person from y language would answer another.

Comment: What's wrong with technologies that you're familiar with? Why choose to do this in an entirely new language?

Comment: It's wise to choose Python 3 to learn because python 3 is the future of python. Maybe it's not widespread right now, but will be.

Comment: You're right Marcin, but I think persons from Python language can best address this. They are fully aware of language strengths and set backs.

Comment: I think the best choice for technology is Python. Using java is much more time consuming. .net platform, I'm familiar with C# to some extents but really don't feel like using ms dot net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python 3 doesn't work with wxPython right now.  Python 3 does work with pyQT, but it is under GPL, so you will need to buy a license if you do not want to release your software under the GPL.

Comment: [PySide](http://www.pyside.org/) provides bindings for Qt which are LGPL-licensed (and practically identical to PyQt).

Comment: Is PySide currently working on Python 3?  I thought there were still some issues, but I do not follow the project closely.

Comment: According to their FAQ they plan to start work on supporting it this year.

Comment: May they port wxPython to Python 3 later or soon. What about major multimedia libraries? are they inside GUI libraries?